# How to install and get started with Vuetify and Vue.js 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

Where can I find the **new Vuetify version** documentation that's compatible with Vue.js 3 and how do I  install it and setup it using Vue cli :

In vue 2 we do :

```
vue create project-name
```

then :

```
vue add vuetify
```

How can we do that with Vue 3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update 2023**

Just do :

```
npm init vuetify
```

or

```
pnpm create vuetify
```

**Old**

You could follow the new documentation [here](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/) and You could setup it as follows :

Create new vue project :

************************* **VUE CLI** ****************************

```
vue create project-name
```

Then change directory to the new created project to add vuetify

```
cd project-name
```

then

```
vue add vuetify
```

Choose the vuetify 3 preset `Vuetify 3 - Vue CLI (preview 3)` :

```bash
? Choose a preset:
  Vuetify 2 - Configure Vue CLI (advanced)
  Vuetify 2 - Vue CLI (recommended)
  Vuetify 2 - Prototype (rapid development)
  Vuetify 3 - Vite (preview)
❯ Vuetify 3 - Vue CLI (preview 3)
```

this changes the `main.js` file to :

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(vuetify)

app.mount('#app')
```

**`./plugins/vuetify`**

```
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/lib/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/lib/directives'

export default createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
})
```

************************* **VITE** ****************************

Create Vue 3 project following these commands :

```bash
npm init vue@latest
```

Then answer the different prompts :

```bash
✔ Project name: … <your-project-name>
✔ Add TypeScript? … No / Yes
✔ Add JSX Support? … No / Yes
✔ Add Vue Router for Single Page Application development? … No / Yes
✔ Add Pinia for state management? … No / Yes
✔ Add Vitest for Unit testing? … No / Yes
✔ Add Cypress for both Unit and End-to-End testing? … No / Yes
✔ Add ESLint for code quality? … No / Yes
✔ Add Prettier for code formatting? … No / Yes

Scaffolding project in ./<your-project-name>...
Done.
```

finally install vuetify 3 and `@mdi/font`:

```
npm i vuetify@next @mdi/font
```

and change the main.js as above.

You could fork this **[repository](https://github.com/boussadjra/vuetify-3-template/tree/vite)** to get started

Comment: Comment from an absolute beginner: be careful when installing from Vue CLI in an existing project: it will overwrite App.vue (luckily Sublime undo captured it). I'm guessing this problem only happens with beginners who have no idea what they're doing and have to occasionally take a stab at an approach :D