# How to build Vuetify 3 from sources and use it?

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuetify.js, yarnpkg

I want to use current Vuetify 3 version from master in my project.

I cloned vuetify from master (`git clone -b next https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify.git`) to `/home/pavel/vuetify` folder. After that I installed vuetify project (`yarn install`) .

In my project I set

```
  "dependencies": {
    "vuetify": "file:/home/pavel/vuetify",
      ....
  },
  "devDependencies": {,
     ...
     "vuetify-loader": "^2.0.0-alpha.0"
  },
```

However, when I try to build my project I get:

```
$npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: my_project@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: vuetify@undefined
npm ERR! node_modules/vuetify
npm ERR!   vuetify@"file:/home/pavel/vuetify" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vuetify@"^3.0.0-alpha.11" from vuetify-loader@2.0.0-alpha.9
npm ERR! node_modules/vuetify-loader
npm ERR!   dev vuetify-loader@"^2.0.0-alpha.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Could anyone help to build and use current Vuetify 3 version from master.

Comment: master branch has the vuetify 2 source code, next branch points on the version 3, to get started with vuetify 3 please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67347456/how-to-install-and-get-started-with-vuetify-and-vue-js-3

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Thank for your comment, I changed brach (see my edits), but it didn't help. I still can't install my project.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim My project I created using `vue create my_project`, `vue add vuetify`. So, the project was fully created using CLI. Now, I just want to use master version instead of alpha.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build it too (`yarn build vuetify`), and the vuetify package is under `packages/vuetify`, not the root of the repo.
If you just want to try the latest changes they're published automatically to npm: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#nightly-builds